# plt.axis(): How to 'tight' axis hiding boundary NaNs?

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis

I have an array:

```
a = array([
    [ nan,   2.,   3.,   2.,   5.,   3.],
    [ nan,   4.,   3.,   2.,   5.,   4.],
    [ nan,   2.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   2.]
])
```

And I make a filled contour with:

```
plt.contourf(a)
```

So, I'll have it:

[image: Filled Contour]

Nothing happens when I do `plt.axis('tight')`, but I want to hide boundary `NaN` values. How to do it easy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well..

If I consider columns os NaNs in the begin and end, I tried that and it worked:

```
x = np.arange(0,a.shape[1])
plt.xlim([x[~np.isnan(a[0,:])][0],x[~np.isnan(a[0,:])][-1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the min and max xlim using nanmin and nanmax:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([
    [ np.nan,   2.,   3.,   2.,   5.,   3.],
    [ np.nan,   4.,   3.,   2.,   5.,   4.],
    [ np.nan,   2.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   2.]
])
import pylab as plt
xmax= np.nanmax(a)
xmin=np.nanmin(a)
plt.xlim(xmin,xmax)
plt.contourf(a)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thks, but this not solve all the problems because you used z values to limit the x extend. In this case we have a coincidence, but this doesn't work if by chance I have some 0 value or more than 5 value

Comment: @lury Simoes, what happens is you have Nan's in various places in your array?

Comment: I have to subtract all the matrix by some line and not all the columns have values in this line. So I convert all the column in NaN

Answer (score 0):

If the array has the NaNs in a column like in your example, you can do the following way:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = array([
    [ nan,   2.,   3.,   2.,   5.,   3.],
    [ nan,   4.,   3.,   2.,   5.,   4.],
    [ nan,   2.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   2.]
])

b = np.delete(a,0,1)

plt.contourf(b)
```

Comment: I need to do it with a lot of data with different places and extension of boundary NaNs. So I can't just delete the first column